# Let $R$ be a ring, and let $V$ denote the $R$-Module $R$. Determine all module homomorphisms (need clarification of some concepts)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a ring, and let $V$ denote the $R$-module $R$. Determine all module homomorphisms $\varphi : V → V$.

I'm having an issue understanding the structure of this module. The answer is that all homomorphisms are isomorphic to $R$.

Can someone explain how you think about that intuitively? The module itself I suppose is a ring, and it's also over the same ring? How do you imagine that structure?

Furthermore, the homomorphisms being isomorphic to $R$ doesn't make sense to me. The homomorphism is a MAPPING, how is it isomorphic to a ring?

Comment: Does $R$ have a multiplicative identity?

Comment: It's not explicitly mentioned, but I think yes it does.

Answer (score 7):

The module structure is very simple : addition in $V$ is simply the addition in $R$, and the scalar multiplication is given by the product in $R$.

If we assume that $R$ has a multiplicative identity $1$, then every $R$-module homomorphism must satisfy
$$\varphi(x)=\varphi (x\cdot 1)=x\cdot \phi(1);$$
and $\varphi(1)$ can be any element of $R$; indeed, if you define $\phi(x)=x\cdot \alpha$, then you can easily check that
$$\varphi(x+y)=(x+y)\cdot\alpha=x\cdot\alpha +y\cdot\alpha=\varphi(x)+\varphi(y)$$
and
$$\varphi(r\cdot x)=(r\cdot x)\cdot \alpha=r\cdot (x\cdot \alpha)=r\cdot \varphi(x),$$
so that $\varphi$ is an $R$-module homomorphism.

Thus every homomorphism of $V$ is of the form $\phi(x)=x\cdot \alpha$. You can easily add $R$-module homomorphisms $V\to V$ (pointwise), and you can also compose them; these operations, seen as a sum and product, give to $Hom_R(V,V)$ the structure of a ring. Then you can check that
$$\Phi:R\to Hom_R(V,V) : \alpha\mapsto[x\mapsto x\cdot \alpha]$$
is injective and surjective, and that it is *almost* a ring homomorphism. I say almost because it actually is an anti-homomorphism : it preserves operation, but it only preserves the product up to order, in the sense that
$$\Phi(\alpha\cdot \beta)=\Phi(\beta)\circ \Phi(\alpha).$$
Of course, if $R$ is commutative, then $\Phi$ is really an homomorphism. Moreover, I've considered $R$ as a left module; you can also consider it as a right module, and use a similar construction (just switch $x$ and $\alpha$) to obtain a (true) isomorphism of rings between $R$ and $Hom_R(V,V)$.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks so much! but how did you know that's the only homomorphism? For example, why can't I send an element a to 2a, or some other multiple of a?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Any choice of $\alpha$ will give an $R$-module homomorphism.

Comment: I guess I'm trying to imagine the structure of that set of homomorphisms. This is a commutative ring by the way. For example, one homomorphism from v->v will send every element to itself, correct? what about the other homorphisms? My understanding is that you are scaling each element in the ring by some other element in the ring?

Comment: @Lana That's right. What I have shown is that each $R$-module homomorphism $V\to V$ must be some "scaling" by an element of $R$. For example, the identity of $V$ is the scaling by $1$.

Answer (score 2):

The set of all such homomorphisms, $\operatorname{Hom}_R(V,V)$, is a ring in its own right, with the operation being the composition of mappings. So when the answer says that "$\operatorname{Hom}_R(V,V)$ is isomorphic to $R$", I'm sure they mean that this is an isomorphism of rings. And that is actually true, if the ring $R$ has an identity. (Probably somewhere in this chapter of your textbook there's a note saying that this chapter assumes all rings to have an identity.)

Here's the main idea. Let $1_R\in R$ be the identity element of $R$. Assume $\varphi:V → V$ is such a homomorphism. Then it's completely determined by the image of $\varphi$ on $1_R$. More specifically, if $\varphi(1_R)=r$, then for any $x\in R$ we have $\varphi(x)=\varphi(x\cdot1_R)=x\varphi(1_R)=xr$. Then we can define a mapping from $\operatorname{Hom}_R(V,V)$ to $R$ via $\varphi\mapsto\varphi(1_R)$. In other words, we define a mapping $F:\operatorname{Hom}_R(V,V)\to R$ via $F(\varphi)=\varphi(1_R)$ for each $\varphi\in R$. Then it's pretty straightforward to show that this mapping $F$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: You also need commutativity of $R$ for this to be an isomorphism (see my answer). Of course, it's quite possible that all rings are assumed to be commutative with unity.

Comment: How did you know that φ(1R)=r though? is r is just any element in the ring?

Comment: @ArnaudD.: Yes, good point! Writing a quick response, I was pretty careless -- my bad. Two comments then. (1) Note that the OP says "let $V$ denote the $R$-module $R$" -- not a "left module" or a "right module", but just a "module". So maybe their context is that of commutative rings. (2) Even if $R$ is not commutative, then $\operatorname{Hom}_R(V,V)$ has a structure of an $R$-module from the other side, so to speak. (If $V=R_R$ is considered as a right $R$-module over itself, then $\operatorname{Hom}_R(V,V)$ is a left $R$-module.) So this is still an isomorphism -- but of $R$-modules.

Comment: @Lana: Yes, any element. $\varphi(1_R)$ has to be something in $V$ (which is the same as $R$ as a set). So let's call that something $r$.

Comment: @zipirovich Excellent point, I somehow hadn't really thought about seeing $Hom_R(V,V)$ as a module. And you're right, without further specification it seems likely that rings are just commutative in the context.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple :   for any *free* $R$-module $L$, i.e. any $R$-module isomorphic to $R^{(I)}$ for some set $I$, and any $R$-module $M$, one has 
$$ \operatorname{Hom}_R(L,M)\simeq M^I. $$
Let $\mathcal B=(e_i)_{i\in I}$  a basis for $L$. As a homomorphism $u\colon L\longrightarrow M$ is defined in a unique way by the images of the $e_i$s, the isomorphism maps $u\in \operatorname{Hom}_R(L,M)$ to $(u(e_i))_{i\in I}\in M^I$.